# Django queryset retrieve many-to-many choosen field values

Tags: django, orm

I have a class A(Aid,Aname,manytomanyfield) with a many to many relationship to a class B(Bid,Bname).

I have for example three rows in A :
Aid,Aname
1,foo
2,bar
3,baz

I have for example three rows in B:
Bid,Bname
1,foo
2,bar
3,baz

With Django ORM I don't really see the relationship class which contains for example:
Aid,Bid
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
2,3

I want all A rows that match for example class B "3,baz" row.

In django "A.objects.filter(manytomanyfield=B.get(Bname=baz))":
Aid,Aname,Bname
1,foo,baz

Is there a way to retrieve all possible values of A relationship with B after filtering?
I want:
Aid,Aname,Bname,manytomanyfield
1,foo,baz,"foo,bar,baz"

I'm looking for a ",".join(B.values_list("Bname", flat=True) for example in "manytomanyfield".

In django admin, django produce this result with a new request for every line of the html table. I wonder if we can do this with only one ORM request.

Sorry for my english!

Update : I think there is a solution with django orm ExpressionWrapper, F function but I made a new field which stores in cache "foo,bar,baz" so there is only one request to retrieve my objects with their many to many relations.

Comment: Share your models...

Comment: I don't think it has to do with any particular model, I'll try the prefetch_related but I need this python join function to put the result in a field value not an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
A.objects.filter(manytomanyfield__Bname='baz')
```

this can retrieve the same `A` multiple times if the `A` is linked multiple times to a `B` named `baz` or if there are multiple `B` models with `name='baz'`, you can add [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve each `A` at most once:

```
A.objects.filter(manytomanyfield__Bname='baz').distinct()
```

You can retrieve the related `B`s with `some_a.manytomanyfield.all()`, so:

```
qs = A.objects.filter(manytomanyfield__Bname='baz').prefetch_related('manytomanyfield').distinct()

for a in qs:
    print(a.manytomanyfield.all())
```

Comment: I would say, this is not what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: @nippo: "I want all A rows that match for example class B 3,baz rows, in django "...

Comment: I think you make one request by iteration, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, I confirm, one request by line.

Comment: @nippo: you don't use `.values_list`, or `.values` or anything else on `a.manytomanyfield.all()` right? Otherwise it will indeed no longer take the `.prefetch_related` item into account...

Comment: rho, yes I do, I need a "flat" "list" for a json object in html template, I'll try without .values_list and .values just to see if it's a solution to have only one request, thanks !! For my use case, overriding save method with these many to many relation values saved in one cache field is the solution I think.

Comment: @nippo: just use `",".join([b.Bname for b in a.manytomanyfield.all()])`...

Comment: I'll give it a try and look at requests number, thanks so much !!